# Excessive Jpanel element size

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

i've a class named MyPanel extend JPanel, use a GridLayout. each cell contains a single widget (a JComboBox, JTextField, JLabel).

My main class, extend JFrame, use a GridBagLayout. When i'm adding MyPanel to it, it occupy a lot of space (all window go outside my desktop space horizontally). How can i fixit? 
This is the constructor of my mainclass

```
public Client() {
    super("title");
    setResizable(false);

    Container main_container = getContentPane();
    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    main_container.setLayout(layout);

    MyPanel jpanel_acquisto = new MyPanel();
    c.gridx = 0; 
    c.gridy = 0; 
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    layout.setConstraints(jpanel_acquisto, c);
    main_container.add(jpanel_acquisto);

    pack();  
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

}
```

MyPanel constructor

```
    super();
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,5));

    combo_box_produttori = new JComboBox(lista_produttori);
    combo_box_magazzini = new JComboBox(lista_magazzini);
    descrizione = new JTextField("120 caratteri max", DESCRIPTION_MAX_LENGHT);
    label_descrizione = new JLabel("Descrizione");

    quantita_prodotti = new JTextField(20);
    label_quantità = new JLabel("Numero prodotti");

    salva_acquisto = new JButton("Salva acquisto");


    this.add(Box.createGlue());
    this.add(label_descrizione);
    this.add(label_quantità);
    this.add(Box.createGlue());
    this.add(Box.createGlue());

    this.add(combo_box_produttori);
    this.add(descrizione);
    this.add(quantita_prodotti);
    this.add(combo_box_magazzini);
    this.add(salva_acquisto);
```

Comment: With out know what's in the jpanel_acquisto or how its laid out, it's impossible to know what the problem is

Comment: i've paste also MyClass constructor

Answer (score 3):

1) Looking at your code it seems this is what;s making it go offscreen:

`descrizione = new JTextField("120 caratteri max", DESCRIPTION_MAX_LENGHT);`

looks like a `JTextField` with 120 columns?!

Rather use:

- If you must wrap your `JTextField` in a `JScrollPane`. See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more information.
- `JTextArea`/`JTextPane`/`JTextComponent`. See [Using Text Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for more.

You would also wrap the above (JTextComponent) in a `JScrollPane`.

You would do something like:

```
int rows=6;
int cols=20;//20*6=120 characters
JTextArea ja=new JTextArea(rows,cols);
ja.setWrapStyleWord(true);
ja.setLineWrap(true);
JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane(ja);
```

2) Also dont extend `JFrame` class rather create and instance and use that, and make sure you create/manipluate Swing components on the Event Dispatch Thread. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more. i.e:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.add(..);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Gridbag layout automatically stretches and fits its elements according to their sizes If you want to position things using gridbag. You can put empty panels inside the panel to act as buffers, filling space to prevent too much stretching for your main elements.

```
main_container.add(fillerPanel);
main_container.add(jpanel_acquisto);
main_container.add(fillerPanel);
```

you will also need to adjust your gridbag constraints, using the static constants provided [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) is the full list

Comment: But the element size is too big, in MyPanel i've only 2 rows and 4 column. each cell of myPanel is stretched too much! In fact if i add on my mainclass another Jpanel with other things, it occupy the right space

Comment: GridBagLayout doesn't stretch anything by default, it will use the preferred size of the component, unless you tell it that you want it to fill the available space. The problem is with what's in the jpanel_acquisto